# AspectJ @Around is not working in multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, aspectj

I have simple Gradle Spring Boot project with following approximate structure:

```
myproject
├───core
│   └───src
│   │   └───EntryDescription.java
│   └───build.gradle
├───core-web
│   └───src
│   │   └───EntryAspect.java
│   └───build.gradle
├───server
│   └───src
│   │   └───LoginController.java
│   └───build.gradle
├───build.gradle
└───settings.gradle.kts
```

I try to log whenever methods anotated with `@EntryDescription` are called. But the code doesn't seem to even enter Aspect code when conditions are met.

Here's my annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EntryDescription {
    String value();
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class EntryAspect {
    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(EntryDescription)")
    public Object logMethodName(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) call.getSignature()).getMethod();
        EntryDescription entryDescription = method.getAnnotation(EntryDescription.class);
        log.info(entryDescription.value());
        return call.proceed();
    }
}
```

And my controller:

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    @EntryDescription("Customer login process started")
    public void login(@RequestBody LoginRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // Login logic
    }
}
```

I suppose the culprit is the **Gradle** as I managed to get it to work in single module enviroment.

`server/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(":core")
    implementation project(":core-web")
    ...
}
```

`myproject/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "3.0.0" apply false
    id "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving" version "8.0.1"
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.19")
        implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.19")
    }
}
```

`settings.gradle.kts`:

```
rootProject.name = "myproject"

include("core")
include("core-web")
```

NOTE: I tried using `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` on Application class but no help.

Comment: Assuming that you use Spring AOP and not native AspectJ and that you also use component scan, you should add `@Component` to the aspect class and make sure that component scan also picks up the packages in which all code involved (controller, annotation, aspect) resides. If this hint does not help, please post a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub. Your "approximate" layout without configuration or package names does not help much, because the devil is in the details in programming, not in approximate descriptions.